# How to fix error incompatible data types in combination [SQL State=42562, DB Errorcode=-5562]

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I rewrite code.. and get this error:

> incompatible data types in combination [SQL State=42562, DB Errorcode=-5562]

```
MERGE INTO tj USING (VALUES (?) )
  AS vals (created_date) 
  ON vals.created_date  = tj.created_date
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET tj.created_date= vals.created_date
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES  vals.created_date
```

How can i fixed that code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the parameter to the type of the created_date column of tj. The type may be DATE or TIMESTAMP.

```
MERGE INTO tj USING (VALUES (CAST(? AS DATE)) )
AS vals (created_date) 
ON vals.created_date  = tj.created_date
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET tj.created_date= vals.created_date
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES  vals.created_date
```